# mmap size to be adjusted to previous page boundary

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, mmap

Is there a way to determine the previous page boundary of a address.

I know I can determine the next page boundary as

```
size = (size + PAGE_SIZE - 1) & ~PAGE_MASK;
```

But I want to move to the previous page boundary (want to reduce the length)

Thanks,
Ram

Answer (score 4):

Yes,

```
size &= ~PAGE_MASK;
```

will take you to the size rounded down to previous page.